# Как изменить текст кнопки при нажатии? kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

У меня есть функция, срабатывающая при нажатии кнопки:

```
    fun cellPress(view: View) {

    }
```

как мне изменить текст кнопки, не используя `findViewById<>()`?

Что - то вроде этого:

```
    fun cellPress(view: View) {
        view.setText("text")
    }
```

Comment: `(view as? Button)?.setText("Новый текст")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если `View` в этом методе как раз и является той кнопкой, то вы можете использовать рекомендацию *@Alex_Skvortsov*. Правда я бы сделал немного по другому. Т.к. у вас приходит `View` на вход, то предполагается, что там может быть не только `Button`.

Поэтому я бы сделал проверку:

```
if(view is TextView) { // поскольку вам нужно менять текст, то вы можете проверять что это TextView, а не Button т.к. Button наследуется от TextView
    view.text = "your text"
}
```

Еще можно проверить по `id`. Если вы знаете `id` вашей кнопки в разметке.

```
if(view.id == R.id.your_button) {
    (view as TextView).text = "your text"
}
```

Если View это не сама кнопка, а контейнер в котором сама кнопка вы можете использовать метод `findViewById()`:

```
view.findViewById(R.id.your_button)
```